# Clear post data

Tags: php, html

I am creating a login function but once I refresh the page it tries to re-login.
This is my current code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['login-submit']))
    {   
        authenticator::login($_POST['login-username'], $_POST['login-password']);
        $_POST = array();
    }
```

And this is the login function:

```
        public static function login($username, $password)
        {
            session_start();

            if($_SESSION['loggedIn'])
                echo '<script>alert("You are already logged in.");</script>';
            else
            {
                $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE username='$username';"));

                if(md5(md5($password."!#5fDa!2")) === $row[0])
                    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
                else
                    echo'<script>alert("Invalid username or password.")</script>';
            }
        }
```

So once I reload the page the message "You are already logged in" shows up (If logged in ofcourse) which means that the post data is not being cleared probably (I think). Is there another way to do it?